# php curl return empty with FOLLOWLOCATION true

Tags: php, curl

I make a curl request to the address **https**://trimet.ru/contacts/ and get:

> 301 Moved Permanently Location: **http**://trimet.ru/contacts

I change url to **http**://trimet.ru/contacts and get:

> 302 Found

When I try to add curl params:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
```

I get empty result. (safe_mode = off, open_basedir none).

my source code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,2); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,100); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

curl debug:

```
* About to connect() to trimet.ru port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2a03:6f00:1::5c35:6090... * connected
* Connected to trimet.ru (2a03:6f00:1::5c35:6090) port 80 (#0)
> GET /contacts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090716 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Shiretoko/3.5.1
Host: trimet.ru
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: nginx/1.6.3
< Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 20:09:32 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 160
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://trimet.ru/contacts
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host trimet.ru left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://trimet.ru/contacts'
* About to connect() to trimet.ru port 443 (#1)
*   Trying 2a03:6f00:1::5c35:6090... * connected
* Connected to trimet.ru (2a03:6f00:1::5c35:6090) port 443 (#1)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=RU; ST=Saint-Petersburg; L=Saint Petersburg; O=TimeWeb Company Limited; CN=*.timeweb.ru
*    start date: 2014-11-28 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-01-27 23:59:59 GMT
*    issuer: C=US; O=thawte, Inc.; CN=thawte SSL CA - G2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /contacts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090716 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Shiretoko/3.5.1
Host: trimet.ru
Accept: */*
Referer: http://trimet.ru/contacts

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.6.3
< Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 20:09:32 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 184
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://trimet.ru/contacts
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #1 to host trimet.ru left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://trimet.ru/contacts'
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host trimet.ru
* Connected to trimet.ru (2a03:6f00:1::5c35:6090) port 80 (#0)
> GET /contacts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090716 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Shiretoko/3.5.1
Host: trimet.ru
Accept: */*
Referer: https://trimet.ru/contacts

< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: nginx/1.6.3
< Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 20:09:32 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 160
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://trimet.ru/contacts
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host trimet.ru left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://trimet.ru/contacts'
* Re-using existing connection! (#1) with host trimet.ru
* Connected to trimet.ru (2a03:6f00:1::5c35:6090) port 443 (#1)
> GET /contacts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090716 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Shiretoko/3.5.1
Host: trimet.ru
Accept: */*
Referer: http://trimet.ru/contacts

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.6.3
< Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 20:09:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 184
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://trimet.ru/contacts
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #1 to host trimet.ru left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://trimet.ru/contacts'
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host trimet.ru
* Connected to trimet.ru (2a03:6f00:1::5c35:6090) port 80 (#0)
> GET /contacts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090716 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Shiretoko/3.5.1
Host: trimet.ru
Accept: */*
Referer: https://trimet.ru/contacts

< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
```

Comment: you should either, read the trimet API documentation, or contact the maintainers of the API.

Comment: about what API you talking? I do simple GET request to web page

Comment: What other curl options did you set and what do you mean by empty?

Comment: I have added the source code to question. curl_exec return void (nothing)

Comment: @user451555 because it does not init anything and it doesn not execute anything...

Comment: I have added only parameters, not all source code )) I have $ch = curl_init(); and $result = curl_exec($ch); lines